# How do I get Cron Expression over a specific range of dates?

Tags: java, cron

I want to get valid dates between certain dates via cron expression. Is this possible?
Returns only 1 with getNextValidTimeAfter.

For example, my statement is as follows;
0 0 0? MAY, JUN, JUL MON, TUE 2020-2024

This means:
At 00:00:00 am, on every Monday and Tuesday, in May, June and July, between 2020 and 2024

What I want to do is;

To bring the days in this statement between June 2020 and September 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Months are entered as numbers so it should be something like this: `0 0 0 ? 5-9 * 2020-2024`. Look at this [resource](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) for more information.